# Arch Linux arm Xorg doesn't display anything on Raspberry Pi 3 when running startx

Tags: archlinux, xorg, i3, archlinux-arm

On my raspberry pi 3 i have Arch Linux Arm Installed. I installed xorg, i3, and all of the drivers for it. i have my xinitrc file set up like default to run i3:

```
#!/bin/sh

userresources=$HOME/.Xresources
usermodmap=$HOME/.Xmodmap
sysresources=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xresources
sysmodmap=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xmodmap

# merge in defaults and keymaps

if [ -f $sysresources ]; then

    xrdb -merge $sysresources

fi

if [ -f $sysmodmap ]; then
    xmodmap $sysmodmap
fi

if [ -f "$userresources" ]; then

    xrdb -merge "$userresources"

fi

if [ -f "$usermodmap" ]; then
    xmodmap "$usermodmap"
fi

# start some nice programs

if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ] ; then
 for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/?*.sh ; do
  [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
 done
 unset f
fi

exec i3
```

when I run `sudo startx` i get this output

```
X.Org X Server 1.21.1.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Current Operating System: Linux archpi 5.15.68-2-rpi-ARCH #1 SMP Mon Sep 19 17:23:23 MDT 2022 armv7l
Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_compat_alsa=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=1 video=HDMI-A-1:1920x1080M@60 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootwait console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 fsck.repair=yes

Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Sep 22 04:48:27 2022
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Failed to connect to bus: No medium found
dbus-update-activation-environment: error: unable to connect to D-Bus: Using X11 for dbus-daemon autolaunch was disabled at compile time, set your DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS instead
[libi3] ../i3bar/src/main.c i3bar version 4.20.1 (2021-11-03)
[libi3] ../libi3/font.c Using Pango font monospace, size 8
[libi3] ../libi3/font.c Using Pango font monospace, size 8
i3status: trying to auto-detect output_format setting
i3status: auto-detected "i3bar"
[libi3] ../libi3/font.c Using Pango font monospace, size 8
```

the error is in `Failed to connect to bus: No medium found dbus-update-activation-environment: error: unable to connect to D-Bus: Using X11 for dbus-daemon autolaunch was disabled at compile time, set your DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS instead`
I have looked for hours and can not find a way to fix this. After running `sudo startx` My screen just goes dark and I have to reboot. I appreciate any help give, thanks.